# unwanted validation - jquery datepicker mvc 4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the stock function to display a date range in an MVC 4 Razor view.  The start/end dates are part of a filter in my model class.  I want the start/end dates to be optional.

When I submit the form without the start/end filled in it triggers a "Required Field" validation check displaying these lovely messages:

- The Installed Date field is required.
- The InstalledDateEnd field is required.

Yet the form does submit and my filter runs and returns results.

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#InstalledDateStart").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#InstalledDateEnd").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#InstalledDateEnd").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#InstalledDateStart").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried telling the Model that the fields were not required, didn't help:

```
        [Display(Name = "Installed Date")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]        
    public DateTime InstalledDateStart { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public DateTime InstalledDateEnd { get; set; }
```

And this is the markup in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "Search"))
{

    <div class="divSearchBlock">
        <br style="clear:left;" />
        <div>
            <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ConstraintModel.InstalledDateStart)</b>                
            @Html.TextBox("InstalledDateStart", null, new { @class = "divCellContent" })                
            <b>-</b>                
            @Html.TextBox("InstalledDateEnd", null, new { @class = "divCellContent" })                
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
    </div>
}
```

What in the world is causing the fields to be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime`s are not strings. So `AllowEmptyString=true` makes no sense. If you want your `DateTime`s to be nullable declare your model as:

```
[Display(Name = "Installed Date")]
public DateTime? InstalledDateStart { get; set; }
public DateTime? InstalledDateEnd { get; set; }
```

You need the `?` is important because without this the `DateTime` will end up as `DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: I was getting desperate when I added AllowEmptyString.  I was hoping there would be an option for like [Required(IsRequired=false)].  I understand they they were getting set to DateTime.MinValue, I still don't understand how that was triggering client side required validation though.  Making the DateTimes nullable did the trick though.

Comment: The client validation was firing because if you don't make the property nullable the unobtrusive validation adds a Required attribute, because null or empty string is not a valid DateTime. By making it nullable you say if no value is entered, make this property null, which is fine.